# How to store arrays into json file from 2 different php files

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have 2 different php files that am using to fetch data from an API and one JSON file for storing the data. I want that when i run each of the PHP files on the server, my Json file would store array from both PHP files. E.g:

store.json

```
{
 "articles": [{
            "author": "Rozina Sabur",
            "title": "John Cleese to return to new BBC sitcom Edith - despite saying he would never be back",
            "description": "Almost 40 years on from his starring role in Fawlty Towers, John Cleese is set to return to the BBC for a new sitcom.",
            "url": "http:\/\/www.telegraph.co.uk\/news\/2017\/04\/11\/john-cleese-return-new-bbc-sitcom-edith-despite-saying-would\/",
            "publishedAt": "2017-04-11T22:10:11Z"
        }]

"players": [
    {
        "name": "Marcos Alonso",
        "position": "Left-Back",
        "nationality": "Spain",
        "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
        "marketValue": "9,000,000 €"
    }]
}
```

first.php

```
$url = ('myAPI.com');
$jsondata = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

$values = array();
$resp = array();
$date = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');

//get the employee details
foreach ($data['players'] as $myp) {
    $name = $myp['name'];
    $posi = $myp['position'];
    $nation = $myp['nationality'];
    $market = $myp['marketValue'];
    $values[] = array('name' => $name, 'position' => $posi, 'nationality' => $nation, 'marketValue' => $market, 'created' => $date);
}
$resp['players'] = $values; //HERE IS THE PART (PLATERS)
$fp = fopen('myJson.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($resp));
fclose($fp);
```

second.php      The code is pretty much like that of first.php just API diff.

```
.......
........
$values[] = array('author' => $author, 'title' => $title, 'description' => $descrip, 'url' => $ur, 'publishedAt' => $publish);
}
$resp['articles'] = $values; //HERE IS THE MAIN POINT (ARTICLES)
$fp = fopen('myJson.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($resp));
fclose($fp);
```

My problem is, when I run first.php the array replaces that of second.php and vise versa. How to I fix it so that array from both PHP file store in the JSON file like in the store.php file above.

Other ideas on best practices other than 2 diff php files are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both programs are opening the file as 'w'

Change it to this

```
 $fp = fopen('myJson.json','a');
```

just as a note, this will not be a valid 'single json file', but a file of valid json lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $fp = fopen('myJson.json', 'a');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($resp));
fclose($fp);
```

use `a` flag to keep last data

Answer (score 0):

Add this method to a PHP file and require this file in your two PHP files.

```
function storeJson($data, $type)
{
    $prevData = file_get_contents('store.json');
    $arrayData = json_decode($prevData, true);
    if(in_array($type, array_keys($arrayData))) {
        $arrayData[$type] = $data;
        $fp = fopen('store.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($arrayData));
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

In first.php file at the end call the method

```
storeJson($resp, 'players');
```

In the second.php file

```
storeJson($resp, 'articles');
```